# Is there any tool available for analysing queries in MongoDB like pgbadger

Tags: mongodb

We can do a different kind of analysis like slowest/time consuming/Most frequent queries in MongoDB. Is there any tool which will do that for me like PgBadger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest counterpart of PgBadger in MongoDB would be mtools, which is also a log analyzer.

Please see https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools for downloads and information about mtools.

The main difference between PgBadger and mtools is that mtools is not a single tool, but a collection of tools to analyze MongoDB logs.